# Можно ли получить список твитов без их текста?

Tags: twitter, twitter-api

Мне нужны только дата твита и число ретвитов, чтобы быстрее грузилось хочу не запрашивать его текст, это возможно?

Comment: Всё же расписано здесь: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1

Comment: Можете носом ткнуть где это написано?

Comment: У меня встречный вопрос. До того как задать вопрос вы документацию по Twitter API читали, нашли там подобный метод? Если нет, то на что надеетесь?

P.S. можно сделать свой вебсервис, который вырезает лишнее и обращаться из приложения к нему, например.

Comment: Читал и не по разу. 
Свой веб-сервис - с сервера twitter'a всё равно будет закачиваться весь ненужный шлак.

Comment: Размер твита - 140 байт (в Юникоде в 2-3 раза больше). У вас что, диалап или GPRS на телефоне, что вам трафика жалко?

Comment: @kidar2, кого волнует трафик между твиттером и вебсервисом?

Comment: Я пытаюсь грузить все твиты, чтобы построить по ним график: число твитов по дневной динамике.
Мне тексты для этого не нужны, только дата его создания.
А грузить все данные о твите (а это далеко не только сам текст) будет накладно.

Comment: Господа, если желание не гонять по сети лишние атрибуты кажется вам абсурдным, рекомендую посмотреть на API того же ВКонтакте. [users.get](https://vk.com/dev/users.get), аргумент fields — список дополнительных полей, которые необходимо вернуть.

Comment: @Jofsey, какое это имеет отношение к **существующему API твиттера**? Оно такое какое есть, и единственный способ изменить положение дел (кроме долбёжки саппорта самого твиттера) я **пока** вижу только в создании промежуточного веб-сервиса, который вырезал бы лишнее. На само API мы влиять на программном уровне не можем, и обсуждать тут нечего.

Comment: @klopp я говорю, что не стоит обвинять человека — вопрос адекватный, подобная практика распространена.